# Connection String Dynamic C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am using this connection string. It is working. I can select, insert using it. But this method is not dynamic.

```
static string cs = @" Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SayHellox)\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\R Accounts\R Accounts\User_DB.mdf;Integrated Security = True";
```

But when i use this method. It can select, but when i use insert query it gives successfully inserted, but data is not inserted in mdf file.

```
public static string path = Path.GetFullPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
 static string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + path.ToString() + @"\User_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory represents the directory where your application is running. In debug this is the DEBUG\BIN folder not the project folder. Did you check if  the database in DEBUG\BIN is updated?

Comment: If the database file is in the bin\debug folder, are you copying a fresh copy on each build?

Comment: yes. Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy Always

Comment: So then how do you verify that the insert didn't do anything?

Comment: Stop using `AttachDbFileName`. Start using database projects that are deployed to LocalDB as part of building the solution.

Comment: I use Server Explorer to see if data is being inserted or not. In program adapter execute query correctly.